# In Pycharm, Invalid VCS root mapping

Tags: pycharm

The directory \OIDv4_ToolKit is registered as a Git root, but no Git repositories were found there. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This means you've added `\OIDv4_Toolkit` as a VCS based repository, but that directory is not a valid repository. You can either:

1. Remove this repository from `Pycharm` by going to `Settings -> Version Control` and removing it from the list.
2. Or you can make sure that `\OIDv4_Toolkit` is a valid Git repo by running:

```
git clone https://github.com/EscVM/OIDv4_ToolKit.git /OIDv4_ToolKit
```

Comment: Hope it helps! You can accept it as correct for helping others :)